# when to include C++ header file?

Tags: c++

I have two questions:

1. to use compare function, I need to include `<string>`but I don't need to include `<cctype>` to use `isdigit`, `ispunct` etc?
2. what's the difference between `<cctype>` and `ctype.h`? why there is only `<string>` not `string.h`?

Comment: The counterpart for `string.h` is `cstring`, just like all the other C-standard headers when using C++ (and similar to the example you gave concerning `cctype` vs `ctype.h`).

Comment: @WhozCraig so what's the difference between #include <string> and #include <string.h>?

Comment: <string> is for the c++ class "std::string" while <string.h> is for c functions on char array, like strstr()/strcmp(). You don't need to include the other headers separately because <string> includes them already.

Answer (score 1):

1. Always include the headers for everything you use in a file. If you use functionality from A and B, include A and B even if A includes B because tomorrow A might not include B. Why put up with that debugging nightmare if you don't have to? Every file should be self consistent.
   This is also true of system headers. There is no assurance that `string` or any header includes anything. One implementation could include everything down to the kitchen sink and the next implementation, or a different version of the same implementation, could forward-declare what it needs and carry on. Do not assume any chain of includes in any code you do not control.
2. The c* headers primarily wrap  the *.h headers from the C standard library. This places C++-ized versions in the std namespace and takes care of name mangling for you. Often the C++-ized versions have type safety tweaks or are templates that call the C version.